# Convert string to array of 2 bytes in c

Tags: c

I have a string "12345678. I need to convert it in to an unsigned char array. I can create the converted form with the following:

```
unsigned char data[4];
data[0] = 0x12;
data[1] = 0x34;
data[2] = 0x56;
data[3] = 0x78;
```

I have tried using something like

```
for (int i; i < len; i++) {
    data[i] = (unsigned char)strtol(input, NULL, 16);
}
```

But this gives me an ascii representation, not the value.

I've also tried using the following from here https://www.includehelp.com/c/convert-ascii-string-to-byte-array-in-c.aspx

```
void string2ByteArray(char *input, unsigned char *output) {
    int loop;
    int i;

    loop = 0;
    i = 0;

    while (input[loop] != '\0') {
        output[i++] = input[loop++] - 48;
    }
}
```

But this gives `01020304`. How can I do the conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is:

1. extract 2 characters
2. convert them to an integer
3. proceed to next 2 characters

```c
void string2ByteArray(char *input, unsigned char *output) {
    int loop;
    int i;

    loop = 0;
    i = 0;

    while (input[loop] != '\0' && input[loop + 1] != '\0') {
        char buf[3];
        buf[0] = input[loop++];
        buf[1] = input[loop++];
        buf[2] = '\0';
        output[i++] = (unsigned char)strtol(buf, NULL, 16);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or maybe for those who like too much code in a line:  `output[i++] = (unsigned char) strtol((char []) { input[loop], input[loop+1], 0}, NULL, 16);  loop += 2;`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just call `strtoul` (not `strtol`) once.

```c
unsigned long ul = strtoul( s, NULL, 16 );   // "12345678" ⇒ 0x12345678
```

Because from that can be extracted the desired bytes.

```
unsigned char data[ 4 ];                     // 0x12345678
data[ 0 ] = ( ul >> ( 3 * 8 ) ) & 0xFF;      //            ⇒ 0x12
data[ 1 ] = ( ul >> ( 2 * 8 ) ) & 0xFF;      //            ⇒ 0x34
data[ 2 ] = ( ul >> ( 1 * 8 ) ) & 0xFF;      //            ⇒ 0x56
data[ 3 ] = ( ul >> ( 0 * 8 ) ) & 0xFF;      //            ⇒ 0x78
```

You can use a loop, of course.

```
unsigned char data[ 4 ];
for ( int i = 4; i--; ) {
   data[ i ] = ul & 0xFF;
   ul >>= 8;
}
```